# Snapshot of website with provided URL address, through VB.Net code

Tags: vb.net, browser, snapshot

I have seen Google Chrome's preview panes. Whenever you open a new tab, it will show you the last 8 pages that you have visited. I want to do a similar thing except I have a VB.Net code behind the .aspx file which shall give me a list of URL's called form the database. When the page is loaded, the URL's are displayed on it. What I need my code to do is to pick up these URL's, open a web browser in the background, take a snapshot of it, save it, and display it on the screen in a small frame. Any suggestions on how to do this with VB.Net?

Please don't recommend iFrames cause I need a snapshot and not an actual running site in the small snapshot.

Comment: r u serious?? well its about what is the code to take a snapshot of a website, when the url is provided on page.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know that will do such a thing is [ActivePDF's WebGrabber](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/webgrabber/) product.  Then you will have to find a way to convert the generated PDF to a bitmap or something you can actually dynamically render.  [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) might be able to do this.  I know that [Tracker PDF Tools](http://www.docu-track.com/product/pdf-tools-sdk) can, but like WebGrabber, it costs...

Answer (score 0):

Just found [PDFmyUrl.com](http://PDFmyURL.com) which will serve you a PDF or PNG of a URL in thumbnail or original size for free.